# ¿Cómo se almacenan los datos en PythonAnywhere con modelos de Django?

Tags: django, mysql, django-models, bash, sqlite

Desplegué mi aplicación Django en [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), funciona perfecto pero no se como se almacena la data que voy ingresando desde el admin de Django.

¿Se almacena en MySql o sigue guardándose en SQLite?, y ¿cómo puedo ver los registros desde la consola sin el shell de Django?

Comment: Eso depende de como hayas condigurado tu `settings.py` y de los DBMS que te permita usar PythonAnywhere

Comment: Creo que si se puede utilizar Sqlite segun este link: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoTutorial/
Todavía tengo la duda de como visualizar esta data, quizas tenga que instalar un gestor de sqlite.Saludos

Comment: Claro que se puede, SQLite viene incluido en Python, no tienes que instalar nada adicional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que estás un poco confundido con respecto a la configuración y lo que acepta PythonAnywhere.

Como mencionaba en mi comentario, si estás usando SQLite en tu configuración:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
```

No es necesario que instales nada adicional para que esto funcione ya que Python ya viene con un módulo especial para gestionar la conexión con [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). Si este es el caso y asumiendo que PythonAnywhere no te de una interfaz gráfica, puedes usar el comando [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) desde la línea de comandos (sin usar el `shell` de Django como mencionas en tu pregunta):

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Puedes ver la lista de comandos usando `.help`:

```
sqlite> .help
...
```

En general, solo abres el archivo y ejecutas tus sentencias:

```
sqlite> .open "db.sqlite"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1;
...
```

Si, por otro lado, estás usando conexión a MySQL o PostgreSQL tienes que instalar las dependencias y asegurarte que PythonAnywhere te permita instalar paquetes para cada uno.

Comment: La verdad estaba confundido con esto, pero justamente necesitaba usar el comando sqlite para ver mi data. Gracias Cesar y a todos por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa en la configuración de tu proyecto, el valor que almacena `DATABASES`.

En la consola escribe los siguiente:

```
$ python manage.py shell
from django.conf import settings

settings.DATABASES['default']
```

Esto funciona en las versiones 1.8+

Comment: la configuracion que tengo actualmente es
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
El tema es que pude agregar datos y se fueron almacenando, pude recuperarlos sin problemas. Lo que tengo entendido es que pythonanywhere no utiliza sqlite, entonces nose si se almacenan en sqlite o mysql y como ver los datos en bash de alguna forma para poder agregar datos con un archivo.

Comment: Pues la configuración de tu proyecto usa SQLite. No existe una forma de que uses MySQL sin que se lo indiques. No es posible. Si dice `sqlite3` entonces es `sqlite3`.  La información sobre tu dicho sobre [PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoTutorial/) es incorrecta. Para consultar los datos en la consola usa el [`shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/django-admin/#shell)